# Do Events in one parallel universe affect other parallel universe

Tags: parallel-universe, shared-universe, energy

Do Events happening in one parallel universe might have some effects in other parallel universe? In parallel universe, there is a possibility of energy flowing from one parallel universe to another. In that case, why can't a disaster in one parallel universe could lead to the same disastrous(or lesser) in another parallel universe. If thats the case, is there a possibility that already planet Earth was destroyed in some of the parallel universes and that's reason of earthquakes and other stuffs happening here?

Can parallel universe be the reason for paranormal activities(read:ghosts, not aliens) happening in front of our eyes? Is the shift in energy level could show some symptoms of that sort.

Its an idea of how great it would be, if everything in the universe can be just attributed to parallel universe. Please give your thoughts as well. Happy thinking.

Comment: Without specifying a particular work of scifi or fantasy, this question cannot properly be answered. There are so many varying views on parallel universes that no answer can cover them all.

Answer (score 2):

#### Since you have not named any particular reality we will work with the basic assumptions: Universes are big places and describing parallel realities comes with some inherent conceits. Since our understanding of the Universe is still imperfect, when we talk about parallel realities we are usually talking about our particular corner of the Universe, our galaxy, our space empire, our Earth... With that in place let's work with with the ideas presented by most science theory and science fiction works:

- **Answer #1: All events potentially create echos in parallel realities, depending on the importance of the decision and the people making them, the outcomes could come with amazing similarities or drastic differences.** The definition of parallel realities, alternative realities and alternate dimensions are not necessarily the same but often used interchangeably. (See: Memory Alpha - Star Trek: [Parallel Universe](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Parallel_universe))
- **My Own Questions:** The part of this theory which breaks down for me is we only see our one Universe resolved by our particular choices even if there are parallel universes how does the universe, multiverse, omniverse sustain them indefinitely?
- **My Own Questions:** Do they self-resolve at some point in the future? If there is a conservation of matter at the omni-quantum level does that mean ultimately Universes also cease to exist due to choices made by the sentients that live in them? I assume Entropy probably claims most of them as sentients make themselves extinct removing the choice vector from the development of parallel universes...

*This begs the question are parallel universes uniquely based in the idea of choice from sentient life? Would a universe without sentients even HAVE parallel universes?*

- **Answer #2: Any two realities may remain similar if the events between them remain more or less similar. So you could in theory have multiple realities sharing a similar perspective as long as their primary pivotal events remain the same.**  But two or more realities may begin to diverge if their similarity exceeds a certain cosmological value, for example: an Earth where there was NO World War II might look remarkably different from our Earth and indeed any Earth that HAD a second world war. This does not mean better mind you, it could conceivably be worse.
- **Answer #3a:** Most theories of parallel universes imply that said universes are completely unconnected to any other parallel universe in which it shares similarities. No exchange of energy is known or theorized to be exchanged between said universes.
- **Answer #3b:** Awareness between parallel universes also not a well-known trope of science fiction, but it has been shown in some stories where one universe may be aware of another (see: [Fringe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fringe_%28TV_series%29)) and effects from one Universe can have tangential effects on the other. Such activity has been given paranormal references since such events defy standard scientific models of explanation.